# Itext7 pdf.version.not.valid

Tags: itext7

There is an error happen when I read a pdf via Itext7.Then I download the resource code to debug the code.Finally,I find a bug in Itext7.

[image]

Comment: It is should be createPdfVersion(1, 1)? It is already 1.0 exist in PdfVersion.java

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error:pdf.version.not.valid .  When I read a pdf  via   new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new FileInputStrean(new File(...)))),The Itext will get the pdf's version from the pdf and compare with the variable which defined in PdfVersion File.It will show a error pdf.version.not.valid when the pdf version does not exist in the defined variable.

Comment: But there are two save value in the PdfVersion.You can see the image in question.

Comment: In such cases it is always better to have the error visible without the need of opening another link. I inlined the image for you. You were not allowed to do this, so you should have described it in text form. Furthermore, this is not really a question but a bug report. That being said, I'm sure people at itext will become aware of this and fix it soon.

Comment: Thank you very much。I am  sorry for my mistakes

Comment: Voting to close because "this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced" (in the most recent version of iText).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use the most recent version of iText. [This has been fixed](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/kernel/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfVersion.java#L61) in a [commit in August 2016](https://github.com/itext/itext7/commit/a010cb5c144845197f9b39a248cdb58c0e6783f1#diff-8c6073b8af69fa31d9e8012f9ac2f905).